# Creating local objects, prefrence or simply better?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Is it better to create a local object for later use like

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary Dictionary];
```

or

```
NSDictionary * dic = nil;
```

Is it preference thing or is one better then the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not like 'the one is better', it's like 'the other is bad'.

If you're going to assign a new object to it later, initialize it to nil, else (you leak memory by losing the reference to the first object created by error.) - EDIT: no, you're not leaking memory (either because of the autorelease or the automatic reference counting, but anyway, that's an extra unneeded method call.) That is bad.

If it's a mutable collection, create it before you use it, else it will continue being nil and ignoring essentially all messages sent to it, which is also bad.

Conclusion: it's not a matter of preference - you must think logically and choose whichever is suited for the specific purpose you are using it for.

Comment: you are wrong about loosing memory. in the example the instance is autoreleased or if in ARC, taking care of by the wonderful ARC system on compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use that object later, then you should instantiate it with the first option. If you will have to create an object in some if-else block where you will be reinitializing it with some custom values, then the second option is the way to go.

For example the first option:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  [arr addObject:@"string"];
}
```

or

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = nil;
BOOL flag;

if (flag) {
  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"string" forKey:@"myKey"];
}
else {
  NSArray *objects;
  NSArray *keys;
  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
}
```